# Matrix with variable x

Tags: vectors, inverse, matrix-equations

We have matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}(x -2) & 3 & 1 \\ (x -4) & 3 & 2 \\ (x -6) & x & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

for which values ​​of the variable x

a) the matrix does not have an inverse matrix

b)  and its vertical vectors are linearly independent

I have trouble understanding this problem so can someone explain this to me and maybe give a clue how start solving this? How to solve variable x that is in matrix? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The vertical vectors are not linearly independent for any value of $x$. Have a look at the second and last column.

Comment: @Seeker oh okay, can you explain further? Thanks

Comment: $-2$ times the last column plus the second column equals zero. None of these columns depend on $x$ but they do contribute to the columns being linearly independent. Since we can write one of the vectors as a linear combination of the others, the columns are not linearly independent.

Comment: It's 3 x 4 matrix

Comment: If it is a $3\times 4$ matrix, then it is definitely not invertible as only square matrices can be invertible.

Comment: That's what i thought

Comment: Then why have you typed a $4\times 4$ matrix? Maybe consider editing it for any future readers.

Comment: View it as a $3 \times 3$ matrix, see whether the question make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the matrix to $3 \times 3$ matrix.
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}(x -2) & 3 & 1 \\ (x -4) & 3 & 2 \\ (x -6) & x & 3\end{pmatrix}$$
Then there is two solution for part a
and thus there is also solution for part b.
I think the question is more make sense in this form.

You can try to find the determinant.
$$\begin{vmatrix}(x -2) & 3 & 1 \\ (x -4) & 3 & 2 \\ (x -6) & x & 3\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}(x -2) & 3 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & 1 \\ -4 & x-3 & 2\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}(x -2) & 3 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & x-3 & 0\end{vmatrix}\\=-2(x-3)-(x-2)(x-3)=-x(x-3)$$

Comment: Yeah that makes sense! Can you explain a little more how to solve x? My first thought was to do system of equations from the matrix but is that possible? Is there another way?

Comment: Only by looking at the matrix, I think x must be 0 or 3 but I don't know how to prove that

Answer (score 0):

By the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) we have
$$
\det(A)=-(x-3)x.
$$
So the matrix $A\in M_3(K)$ has an inverse if and only if $x\neq  0,3$ in the field $K$.